# Is there a way to store "extensible enums" in an EnumMap?

Tags: java, interface, enums

I'm referring to the paradigm in Item 34 in Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.  I would like to take the method he's using which is to have each related `enum` implement a base interface, and initialize an `EnumMap` from the "sub-enums." See the code section below.   I'm getting a syntax error which I don't understand.  I'm not set on this method of implementation, but I would like to understand why it won't work.

Note that this example assumes each class definition is in its own file.

```
public interface BaseEnum { 
    ... 
}

public enum EnumOps1 implements BaseEnum { 
    ... 
}

public class Widget {
    public Widget() {
         regMap = new EnumMap<EnumOps1, WidgetData>(EnumOps1.class);

         for (EnumOps1 op : EnumOps1.values()) {
             regMap.put(op, getWidgetData(op.key()));  // line with syntax error
         }
    }

    protected Map<? extends BaseEnum, WidgetData> regMap;
}
```

Syntax error detail:

> method put in interface java.util.Map`<K,V>` cannot be applied to given types
>     required: capture#1 of ? extends BaseEnum, WidgetData
>     found: EnumOps1, WidgetData

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a problem with your wildcarding.  You should declare your map as `Map<BaseEnum, WidgetData>` and also your EnumMap as ex. `HashMap<BaseEnum, WidgetData>`

There's plenty of discussion of why this is true on SO, but see [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for example.

**Edit**

Sadly, you're right - you can't use an EnumMap there.  This is because you are trying to use an interface, and EnumMap stipulates (as it requires a type `T extends Enum<T>`) that it must be an Enum only.

Your choices basically boil down to

1) Use an `EnumMap<EnumOps1,...>` and lose out on the polymorphism

2) Use a `HashMap<BaseEnum,...>` and everything works fine but you have to use a non-Enum map.

3) Use wildcards as you are trying, but you'll run into the PECS restrictions I linked earlier e.g. you can add or remove elements but not both (`super` vs `extends`)

Comment: When I try that declaration and instantiation, I get another syntax error: type parameter BaseEnum not within its bound. That error is on the instantiation line (regMap = ...) Any ideas?

Comment: I agree with the correctness of your response.  However, it's not totally clear why that particular line is throwing the error.  In all cases where the EnumMap is being instantiated or called, an enum is being passed to it.  I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: The code is the same as in the original post.  I'm looking to get a better understanding of what is wrong with passing the enum to the EnumMap.put method when the EnumMap is instantiated like I have it.  I understand that the other choices you've listed will work.

Comment: The problem is that the type of your Map key is `? extends BaseEnum` which means that the `regMap` variable has keys which are **some unspecified subclass** of `BaseEnum`.  It is **never** safe to add an element to this, because based on the static type (which is **some unspecified subtype**) you cannot know what specific subtype you must add to the collection.  If you get it wrong you will violate type-safety and the compiler cannot verify it, so it disallows it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that helps.  EnumOps1 is not the same as BaseEnum because generics aren't covariant so the compiler complains.  The thing that was throwing me off is the examples in the book.  The examples are correct and good, but the type is always static/known at compile time.  It's just done in a clever way.  Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I did after hours of research and attempts.  I wanted to reap the benefits of EnumMap and not be restricted to just one enum class but rather many different ones that were implementing the same interface.
In the below example, I had an interface named Layout that I had a few enum classes extending it.  I then created a helper class, Record, which utilized the EnumMap to handle and store mapping some String values to the enums in my enum class and I needed it to accept different enum classes that were all extending the Layout interface. So I created the following class (its shortened below to give an idea):

```
public class Record<T extends Enum<T> & Layout>
{
    private Map<T, String> fields;

    /**Constructor accepting the class name of one of the enums implementing layout
    */
    public Record(Class<T> layout_type)
    {
        fields = new EnumMap<T, String>(layout_type);
        for (T type : layout_type.getEnumConstants())
        {
            fields.put(type, "");
        }
    }

    /*Here's an example of a method that manipulates (adds or replaces) an enum map  
    *item and its corresponding String value in the enum map
    *This won't warn any unchecked exceptions or anything and I can pass any
    *enum from my enum class that implements layout enum.NAME 
    */
    public void setRecordFieldValue(final T item, String value)
    {
        fields.put(item, value);
    }
}
```